# How to replace bathtub pull-up drain stopper with screen/mesh for hair?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, drain

I have a bathtub which also is a shower, and it has a twist-and-pull type drain. Currently I never actually use the bathtub for taking a bath, only showers. Unfortunately it keeps getting clogged with hair.

[image: Twist-pull drain]

On the one hand I could get a hair stopper that fits over it:

[image: Hair trap cover]

But I'd prefer to just install a mesh/screen that is always open and looks much nicer:

[image]

Is there an easy way to convert this type of drain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to do this pretty easily.

To remove the stopper, simply unscrew the top of the handle of the drain stopper, then unscrew the underlying screw in the shaft to pull out the drain cover completely. Then, you'll have the cradle-thing that holds the stopper. You might be able to leave that in place (I grew up in a house that had the stoppers taken out but the "cradles" left in place, and two women with long hair would share the bath. We took turns cleaning out the drain) and place the mesh catcher over it. [See this video](http://youtu.be/CFQq1-Gqwwg) for a demo (It should be region-free.)

You'll probably want to put down putty or some sort of long screw from the drain to the "cradle" in order to keep it in place.